# screen flickering

Tags: nvidia

I have HP G60 notebook. Just installed ubuntu. Now screen flickers when mouse moves over browser and apps. Also can't find a way to access Grub. Booting doesn't offer me a choice. NVIDIA AM 64. Did try to find driver, took all day to install, it was Linux and didn't work, so reinstalled ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common bug with NVIDIA GPUs. I did a blog post on it, [which you can read here](https://sudodblog.wordpress.com/2015/01/31/ubuntu-tech-snippet-12-fix-the-nvidia-screen-flicker-bug-in-ubuntu/).

I'll also provide the basic instructions here.

---

First off, you're going to need the CompizConfig Settings Manager software. If you don’t already have it installed, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a Terminal.

Once that terminal is open, enter `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You’ll probably need to enter your password, but once you do it will install. Don’t close the terminal.

Once installed, go ahead and enter `sudo ccsm`. This will launch CompizConfig Settings Manager. It will show you a warning about the program being very powerful, probably say something along the lines of “With Great Power comes Great Responsibility”. Just click okay.

Once it comes up, search for workarounds and select the only option that comes up:

[image]

Then, scroll down and select the **Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint** option:

[image]

Once you’ve done that, you can close Settings Manager, and you’re done! This should have helped if not resolved the screen flicker issue for you!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps, but I am having the same issue on the same Laptop but with an AMD Card. What helped for me to fix the issue on the instant and without a reboot was to simply change the rendering backend in the display settings from OpenGL 2.1 to 3.1.

I have to see if the issue will return or not, but for now it looks great.